# External hard drive with corrupt data

Tags: usb-storage

I have a Western Digital 120gb external hard drive that I have been using for about 3 years with multiple OS'es to transfer files. Recently, a folder with some data in it cannot be deleted. I can add and remove files anywhere else on the drive but I'm unable to get rid of this particular folder.

I have tried to format the drive with Windows disk management but because of this corruption it won't let me format the drive at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: Delete the partition, then create a new one and format, if it still fails format, replace the drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would download [Knoppix](http://www.knoppix.net/) or [Backtrack](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/) and use the `shred` command to overwrite the bad data.

`#shred /dev/{usbdrive}`

Traditionally, the Quick Format under Windows doesn't actually delete any data, it only deletes the index nodes on the partition. By running `shred` you will actually zero out the bits of the corrupted or bad area.

Also, this may be a job for scan disk / chkdisk. You need to face the fact that sometimes drives fail, or sectors on the drive become damaged and can no longer be utilized. Running `chkdisk /r` will attempt to repair the damanged sectors.

Comment: chkdisk /r fixed the issue. Thanks